# MINIFS formula in a date range and excluding zero

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the following formula to find the minimum number in a date range.  The formula is working great, but I need to exclude zero from my results.

```
=MINIFS($J$2:$J$2000,$I$2:$I$2000,">=1/1/2018",$I$2:$I$2000,"<2/1/2018")
```

I am new to formulas that are this complex and have no idea how to make this work. Note that MINIFS is an Excel 2013 and higher function.

Comment: You don't need to use `minifs`. I tried with `min` and it worked, it will ignore the blank cells and will give you the minimum date (which is actually a number in fact)

Comment: I received a #VALUE! result.  The cells are not blank, they actually contain a zero.  I am guessing by the result, that this makes a difference.

Comment: You should use `=min(A1:A2000)` and it will give you the earliest date in that range

Answer (score 1):

You have *literally* stated that you want to exclude rows where $J$2:$J$2000 is equal to 0

Just add that as another condition:  `$J$2:$J$2000, "<>0"`

Comment: Where in my formula would I add that?

Comment: @A.Kuritz Put it at the end, as `criteria_range3` and `criteria3`: `=MINIFS($J$2:$J$2000, $I$2:$I$2000, ">=1/1/2018", $I$2:$I$2000, "<2/1/2018", $J$2:$J$2000, "<>0")`

Answer (score 0):

Since MINIFS is an excel 2016 function, this is a formula for previous versions that support the AGGREGATE function.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$J$2:$J$2000/(($I$2:$I$2000>=date(2018,1,1))*($I$2:$I$2000<date(2018,2,1))*($J$2:$J$2000<>0)),1)
```

proof of concept:
[image: POC]

NOTE:  This assumes you want to exclude 0 results from column J.  If negative values are also to be excluded, change the <>0 to >0.

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I tested it:

```
=MINIFS($J$2:$J$2000,$I$2:$I$2000,">=1/1/2018",$I$2:$I$2000,"<2/1/2018",$J$2:$J$2000, "<>0")
```